# How to style inside an AngularJS modal form?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an AngularJS Modal Bootstrap form working. How do I style the text inside the form? In the example below, I'd like 'Name' to be Bold. I've tried label, divs, ng-class but that seems to get stripped out when Angular processes the form.

```html
    <form novalidate class="simple-form">
      <div ng-class="col-sm-2 control-label">Code:</div> {{Code}} 
      <label>Name:</label> {{Name}}
      <label>Our Name:</label><input type="text" ng-model="Our_Name" />
</form>
```

When I view the source it always comes out:

```html
<form novalidate="" class="simple-form ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid ng-binding">
      Code: C11 Name: Accredited Surety Cas Co.
      Our Name: <input type="text" ng-model="Our_Name" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"><br>
</form>
```

Thanks for looking.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to style, Label Name or Label Value ? Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c6c6hnf9/1/). Is this you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm trying the style the label in an  AngularJS Modal Bootstrap form. The popup form doesn't style. When I look at the source class="simple-form ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid ng-binding" and nothing in there is styled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you have included [bootstrap.css](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css) in your code. And for modal window you need to add modal specific classes like below.

```
<form novalidate>
  <div class="modal-dialog simple-form">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        //your rest html
      </div>              
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c6c6hnf9/3/).

I hope this is what you are looking for.
Thanks

Comment: I understand better now. Thank you for your help Kailash.